# mvc routing Encode vs Url.Encode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encoding, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-encoding

I have mvc5 site and there are problem with Encode links.

```
        string text = "Guns N' Roses";
        string Link1 = Url.Action("Artist", "Index", new { id = text }); // -> Index/Artist/Guns%20N'%20Roses
        string Link2 = "Artist/Index/" + Url.Encode(text); // -> Artist/Index/Guns+N%27+Roses
        string Link3 = Url.Action("Artist", "Index", new { id = Url.Encode(text) }); // -> /Index/Artist/Guns%2bN%2527%2bRoses
```

For links I use Url.Action and it route params and return link. In that example it return param "**Guns N' Roses**" coverted as "**Guns%20N'%20Roses**", but when I just covert param by Url.Encode it return "**Guns+N%27+Roses**".

How come they not return the same? How force Url.Action make params like Url.Encode? Because if i use wrap param with Url.Encode and then make link with routing it make double encoding, which is not correct.

So how to make Url.Action return links like "**Artist/Index/Guns+N%27+Roses**"?

Duke

Comment: You can try  Url.Action("Artist", "Index") + "/"+ Url.Encode(text);

Comment: @hsnbl thanks. it works, but looks a bit ugly in code. I hope there should be some way change how it converted in Url.Action

Comment: your welcome :) I create an asnwer for this question. To make it beautiful you can use 
string.Format("{0} / {1}}", Url.Action("Artist", "Index") , Url.Encode(text))

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `Url.Action()` and `Url.Encode()` like following.

```
string text = "Guns N' Roses";
Url.Action("Artist", "Index") + "/" + Url.Encode(text);
```

or

```
string text = "Guns N' Roses";
string.Format("{0}/{1}",Url.Action("Artist", "Index"), Url.Encode(text));
```